# Installing ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup and got errors

Tags: angular, datetime, ngx-bootstrap

All dependencies are installed already though.

```
ERROR in node_modules/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup/dist/lib/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup.module.d.ts:2:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, 
but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

    This likely means that the library (ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup) which declares DatetimePopupModule has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. 
Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

    2 export declare class DatetimePopupModule {
```

ts file:

```
import { BsDropdownModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/dropdown';
import { DatepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';
import { TimepickerModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/timepicker';
import { DatetimePopupModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup';
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    DatepickerModule.forRoot(),
    TimepickerModule.forRoot(),
    DatetimePopupModule.forRoot(),
    FormsModule
  ],
```

html:

```
<datetime-popup [(value)]="myDate" [closeButton]="myCloseOptions"></datetime-popup>
```

Documention [got here](https://developer.aliyun.com/mirror/npm/package/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup/v/1.1.1)
Check [Demo here](https://gillardo.github.io/ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup/)

Any recommendation for other datetime picker pop-up that i can use?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, make sure that you are using the latest version of ngx-bootstrap.

I just upgraded an app to Angular 9 (with Ivy), and had to use the latest, but it's working fine, including the datetime-popup.

Comment: heres the version im using : 

"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup": "^5.1.0",

Answer (score 0):

Well, ngx-bootstrap actually does not related to ngx-bootstrap-datetime-popup in any way, it was made by different authors.

However, the error, that you got mostly looks like it has to be updated by the author, to have full Ivy support (obviously). It's better to create an issue on library's repo and ask author about it